# How can i disable log requests sent to http://127.0.0.1:19000/logs in my Expo / React Native project?

Tags: react-native, expo, metro-bundler

I noticed that my expo project is sending huge amount of post requests to http://127.0.0.1:19000/logs in development mode.
I couldn't find any piece of documentation whether it is a necessary thing or it is something we can disable.

How can i disable it completely?

Answer (score 0):

I am also getting this issue. I think this is some kind of expos packages issue. I just cancel the terminal process and run it again.